# Squid deny acl does not work as documented

Tags: proxy, squid

I have the following Squid config on my server

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

If I connect to facebook use my server as proxy

```
curl -L 'https://facebook.com' -x 'myserver'
```

The request is denied, error message is `TCP_DENIED/403`,
but if I change the setting to

```
http_access allow CONNECT SSL_ports
```

It works.

As the Squid document said,

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

allows connect only through the SSL_ports. Why this setting denies my request?

Answer (score 0):

The, ACL `CONNECT` will identify all the requests with the HTTP method CONNECT.

Now, let's see Squid's default configuration for using the CONNECT method:

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

By default, Squid will allow the CONNECT HTTP method only for SSL port 443, which is the
standard port for HTTPS communication. Again, we should go with the default configuration
and add more ports to the SSL_ports ACL as the need arises.